# OpenBSD: downloading and installing php packages

Tags: command-line, package-management, openbsd

How do I download and install packages from the `command line` in `OpenBSD`?

As an example, in Fedora, to download the `php pecl-memcached` package from the `command line`, I just do this:

```
dnf install php php-pecl-memcached
```

I have searched through the net but found no answer relating to it ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install a package by-

`# pkg_add packageName`

For downloading PHP packages-

```
# pkg_add php
# pkg_add php-fpm
# pkg_add php-mysql
```

Discover more information at the [openbsd faq](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq15.html#PkgInstall)

Comment: Oh thank you. Lemme try it now

Comment: Additionally, the package mentioned in the question is called `pecl74-memcached` (for PHP 7.4) on OpenBSD 6.7. There are also variants for PHP 7.2 and 7.3.